Pandas: Delete rows inexistant from a dataframe based on another
I am completely blanking as to how to solve my issue. I have two dataframes. The first looks like this:
dataframeHandRight
------------------
Subject     Recording   Label       Timestamp   Value
S001        R001        HandRight   0           1.2345678
S001        R001        HandRight   0.1         4.815162342
S001        R001        HandRight   0.2         3.14
...
S001        R030        HandRight   42.0        2.1
S001        R030        HandRight   42.1        -0.3
S001        R030        HandRight   42.2        0.2

The second looks like this:
dataframeAudio
--------------
Subject     Recording   Label       Timestamp   Value
S001        R001        Audio       0           9.9999
S001        R001        Audio       0.1         -13
S001        R001        Audio       0.2         7.77
...
S001        R030        Audio       42.1        18.8
S001        R030        Audio       42.2        7.33
S001        R030        Audio       42.3        41.26

Sometimes, the audio recordings are a few timestamps longer than the HandRight recordings (in the example above, there is a row for recording R030/timestamp 42.3 in the Audio dataframe, but not in the HandRight dataframe).
How can I process dataframeAudio to only keep the rows having a pair recording/timestamp that exists in dataframeHandRight?
Thank you :)

Rows that match in both dataframes is a join. Does that help?

As noted above, this can be done by combining two dataframes.
To do this, we will get only timestamps from dataframeHandRight and combine them with dataframeAudio
merged_df = pd.merge(
    dataframeAudio,
    dataframeHandRight['Timestamp'],
    on=['Timestamp'],
    how='inner'
)


Hi! This (almost) worked! I needed to add the "Recording" component there, so by adapting your code: merged_df = pd.merge(dataframeAudio, dataframeHandRight[['Recording', 'Timestamp']], on=['Recording', 'Timestamp'], how='inner')
Thank you!
